# Unity как правильно создавать и загружать AsseteBundle для iOS?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Добрый день уважаемые.
Возникло пару вопросов по Unity.
1. В доках говориться, что выполнение скриптов из assetbundle на iOS не возможен. Так ли это? Ибо по некоторым источникам вроде как все выполняется (как пишут).
2. Вычитав определенную информацию, погуглив, посмотрев пару видосиков на YouTube, я пришел к выводам, что AssetBunble добавлять при сборке в билд, + в ручную указывать имя ассета в сборке. То есть при загрузки новых ассетов надо заново пересоберать само приложение. Так ли это?

Comment: Ассеты можно подкачивать уже после сборки приложения. Заново его пересобирать необязательно.

Comment: @suvitruf
ОК, тогда каким образом?
Все, что я смог найти или сделать, подключение сцены в билд и только тогда отображение загружаемой сцены

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle.html

Comment: Спасибо! сейчас поизучаю.